# Performances of dm-crypt vs. ecryptfs

Tags: encryption, dm-crypt, performance

The only information I found about the difference of performance between *dm-crypt* (LUKS mode) and *ecryptfs* is that given that ecryptfs operates at filesystem-level, it may be slower when doing operations on a lot of small files.

Given that they both seem to use AES as cipher, in what situation can dm-crypt be faster than ecryptfs?

Comment: When comparing io performance, you need to specify the workload. Sequentially writing single 1TB file is very different from compiling chromium.

Comment: Not sure why this question is downvoted as its seems a reasonable question to me. Can downvoters explain why?

Comment: @lepe I was wondering too :/ Maybe the question is too broad ?

Comment: @YdobEmos: Maybe, but I still feel that the question is pretty straight forward. Anyway, if you are concerned about using one over the other, I would recommend you to make yourself a benchmark for your specific case.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but my experience with ecryptfs was dismal for small files with fast reads and writes on desktop grade hardware. It may be enlightening to check out: https://lwn.net/Articles/639427/ about ext4 encryption, which talks about the layered effects of ecryptfs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a source at the moment, but looking at the speed gap, dm-crypt seems to use the AES-NI hardware acceleration, where ecryptfs doesn't. That could explain the huge difference.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience ecryptfs has been much slower than dm-crypt but better in read operations than dm-crypt. Not sure why though. I did benchmarks using iozone.

Comment: Could you post your benchmark results and explain how you obtained them?  That would make for a very good answer.